# Intuition behind the math of Diffraction

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

Is there an intuitive way to understand why the diffraction patterns arising from an arbitrary aperture is Mathematically the Fourier Transform of this aperture function?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Huygen's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) that every point on a wave acts as a source of secondary waves? If so, I don't find it all that surprising that (in some approximation), the diffraction is made up of a sum/integral of complex exponentials (waves).